# return specific items in json object using bash

Tags: arrays, json, bash, curl, jq

I'm trying to take a json response (from a curl command and jq installed on my linux comp) with multiple objects, and edit each one with a for loop. The problem is I don't understand how to take each {} and convert them into separate objects. For example, my json response is:

```
{
  "Name": "testuser1",
  "Username": "testuser1",
  "Url": "www.test1.com"
}
{
  "Name": "testuser2",
  "Username": "testuser2",
  "Url": "www.test2.com"
}
```

Ideally, I want to refer to each by a number. For example "echo $item | jq '.Name[0]'" for the

```
{
  "Name": "testuser1",
  "Username": "testuser1",
  "Url": "www.test1.com"
}
```

When I run the command above i get the following error.

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:1): Cannot index string with number
```

I would like to run a forloop for each object.

Comment: BTW, `echo "$item"`, not `echo $item`. See [BashPitfalls #14](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo) -- if your JSON contains a whitespace-surrounded `*` in a string, for example, that could suddenly turn into a list of files in your current directory if expanded without quotes.

Comment: It would help if you followed the mcve guidelines (stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) more closely. If you want to "edit" each object, then perhaps you not need any iteration in bash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do two things: one, use the `-s` option so that each separate object becomes an element of a single array. Two, you are trying to index the `Name`, instead of accessing the `Name` attribute of an array element.

```
$ jq -sr '.[].Name' tmp.json
testuser1
testuser2
```

If you wanted to refer to a specific element of the stream, you could:

```
$ jq -sr '.[1].Name' tmp.json
testuser2
```

With that (and assuming none of your names will contain newlines), a proper loop would look like

```
while IFS= read -r name; do
    ...
done < <(jq -sr '.[].Name' tmp.json)
```

Comment: Note that there may be no need to use -s at all, as jq is stream-oriented.  Furthermore, even if some kind of reduction is required, then provided your jq has `inputs`, it may be advantageous not to use the -s option, as it may require more memory than is necessary.

Comment: True; I used `-s`  mainly to emphasize where the indexing *would* apply. For the example given, `jq -r '.Name'` would work just as well.

Answer (score 0):

To select only the first name, you need to do the indexing **before** trying to go into the `Name` element:

```
jq -rs '.[0].Name'
```

By contrast, for a loop, the `while read` approach [given by @chepner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50650179/14122) is indeed appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

jq is stream-oriented, so if you want to perform some operation on each object, then it might be sufficient to define that operation in jq, and let jq handle the stream without further ado.

If for some reason you need the index of each item in the stream, then you can avoid the `-s` option if your jq has `inputs` (as does jq 1.5).
(Avoiding the `-s` option saves memory.)

The following assumes that your jq does have `inputs`; that indexing is 0-based; and that jq is invoked with the -n option.

### Generating an index

```
foreach inputs as $input (-1; .+1; [., $input])
```

This will produce a stream of [INDEX, ITEM] arrays. You can then tack on further jq filters using jq's pipe operator (`|`).

### Selecting the i-th item from a stream of JSON entities.

For the sake of illustrating a suitable method for invoking jq, let's suppose the stream of JSON entities comes from `curl COMMAND`, and that we want the second item (that is, with index 1).

#### Invocation

```
curl COMMAND | jq --argjson i 1 -n -f program.jq
```

(Note the `-n` command-line option!)

#### program.jq

```
def get($i):
  label $done
  | foreach inputs as $input (-1; .+1;
      if $i == . then $input, break $done else empty end);

get($i)
```